# Can't return value inside Async Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, promise, firebase-authentication

I have a file dedicated to handling Authentication functions for my React Native App. One of these functions `getJWToken` is an anonymous async function that tries to get the current user token by the following means:

```
const auth = db.auth() 
// db === (Firebase.apps.length === 0 ? Firebase.initializeApp(config) : Firebase.app())
// the configuration of the Firebase DB occurs in a config file and db is exported.

const getJWToken = async () => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            user.getIdToken()
                .then(function(idToken) {
                    return idToken;
                })
                .catch(
                    (error) => {
                        console.log("Cannot get User Token: ", error);
                    }
                )
        }
    });
}
```

Through `console.log` I'm able to see that the function returns the token as it's suppose to. The issues arrives when I'm using it in another async function in another file like so:

**Service Folder index.js**

```
import * as Auth from './AuthServices'

export {Auth}
```

**App.tsx**

```
// App.tsx
import {Auth} from './src/services'
// The rest in inside an Async Function
signOut: async () => {
 let token
 token = await Auth.getJWToken()
 console.log("token: ", token) // results in undefined
}
```

Token results in `undefined`. I have no means of returning the token value from the promise function. I've tried using `return` on `auth.onAuthStateChanged` but that results in token evaluating to `[Function Bound]`. `await` on `auth.onAuthStateChanged` does nothing either. I'm truly stumped.

Comment: Not sure if promises are the best use for this. (1) You probably want `onIdTokenChanged` instead of `onAuthStateChanged` if you're grabbing the idToken. (2) These trigger every time there's a change—a promise can only resolve a value once. You should be listening for this event and storing the result somewhere. Then, `getJWToken()` can fetch wherever you've cached the token.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return at two more places as show in the code . Please reply with this modification, ket us c

```js
const auth = db.auth() 
// db === (Firebase.apps.length === 0 ? Firebase.initializeApp(config) : Firebase.app())
// the configuration of the Firebase DB occurs in a config file and db is exported.

const getJWToken = async () => {
   return  auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
           return  user.getIdToken()
                .then(function(idToken) {
                    return idToken;
                })
                .catch(
                    (error) => {
                        console.log("Cannot get User Token: ", error);
                    }
                )
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I no longer use this code snippet I was able to solve it like so:

```
getJWToken 
export const getJWToken =  async () => {
 let result;
 // await is needed here
  await auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
          console.log("user")
          // save this promise to result
          result = user.getIdToken()
              .then(function(idToken) {
                  return idToken;
              })
              .catch(
                  (error) => {
                      console.log("Cannot get User Token: ", error);
                  }
              )
      }

});
// return the user.getToken() promise
return result
```